# Issue with SSIS Package parameter - dtexec

Tags: sql, ssis, dtexec

I am trying to execute SSIS package using command line dtcexe but I am getting error.

Error I get - **Description: The package path referenced an object that cannot be found: "\Package.Variables[$Project::p_cityID].Properties[Value]". This occurs when an attempt is made to resolve a package path to an object that cannot be found.**

```
Begin
declare @p_cityId varchar(10) = '%'
declare @p_count varchar(10) = '-1'

declare @query varchar(4000) = 
'dtexec /Project C:\SSIS\DUTPackages.ispac /Package pmtCity.dtsx /decrypt pass@123'
+ ' /SET \Package.Variables[$Package::p_cityID].Properties[Value];''' +  @p_cityId + ''''
+ ' /SET \Package.Variables[$Package::p_count].Properties[Value];''' + @p_count + ''

exec xp_cmdshell @query

End
```

So far I have tried using -

```
Package.Variables[$Project::p_cityID].Properties[Value]
Package.Variables[User::p_cityID].Properties[Value]
```

But had no luck.

Can anyone point me to right direction and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2014#parameter) The following example of running a package from the .ispac project file and setting package and project parameters.

/Project c:\project.ispac /Package Package1.dtsx /SET **\Package.Variables[$Package::Parameter];1** /SET \Package.Variables[$Project::Parameter];1